# Bootstrap navbar not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, navbar

I'm making a website using this theme:

https://bootstrapthemes.co/item/jwood-photography-portfolio-html-landing-page-template/

But there's a problem: the navbar doesn't work on Chrome. It looks good but doens't take you anywhere when clicked. It works perfectly on IE. Can you help me, where's the problem with this? I think it worked when i downloaded the theme a couple weeks ago. I haven't made any changes to the code that would effect the navbar.

The live preview page has the same problem:

https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/html/one-page-portfolio-landing-page/

Comment: give us some code, please.

Comment: @Goran he did give the website which contains the full code ^^ That's his problem, he doesn't know where is the problem coming from

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy oops, my bad.

Comment: Since when do we consider external code ontopic on Stack Overflow? @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: Confirmed: Does not work on Chrome/Mac and on Opera/Mac either. Does work on Safari/Mac and on Firefox/Mac.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt we do not, but I found it easier to give directly the source of the problem. Why does it bother you 4 months later? :)

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In **main.js** change this:

`$('#navbar-collapse')`

to this

`$('.navbar-collapse')`

and it will help,
Still there is a problem with menu background on mobile devices.

Comment: to keep background menu on mobile devices it should be changed:  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth > 200)

Comment: This solves the problem. I have no idea why it works in other browsers - `$('#navbar-collapse').find('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').length` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

In the live demo HTML header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

**It's still valid to use IE=edge, chrome=1** but the chrome frame project has been wound down (Jan 2014) so it is redundant for browsers that don't already have plugin installed. To pass the W3C validator the **chrome=1** should be removed. This could be a cause.

Comment: Did you try your answer before posting it? This doesn't work.

Comment: Tried removing the **chrome=1** from the code but it didn't help. Cleared my browser cache also and still not working

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the jQuery Plugin localScroll being a **very**  old version (1.3.5 from 2014, as opposed to 2.0.0 being the current version):

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/issues/38

Remove the plugin from plugins.js and replace it with the current version. That should fix the issue.